# Example for ldap_sasl_bind function?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I have searched in vain on how to implement OpenLDAP function `ldap_sasl_bind`.

The application being developed requires me to access Active Directory using OpenLDAP. I must bind to AD and every sample program I've looked through uses `ldap_simple_bind` or similar function which have been deprecated and hence I cannot use them.

The `ldap_sasl_bind` function has a parameter for user credentials and I must provide user name and password for authentication. The problem is the cred parameter accepts pointer to `struct berval` which I have no idea how to implement.

The definition of `berval` in microsoft docs is given below:

```
    typedef struct berval {
    ULONG bv_len;
    PCHAR bv_val;
    } LDAP_BERVAL, *PLDAP_BERVAL, BERVAL, *PBERVAL, BerValue;
```

Here's the `ldap_sasl_bind` function definition in OpenLDAP:

```
    int ldap_sasl_bind(LDAP *ld, const char *dn, const char 
   *mechanism, struct berval *cred, LDAPControl *sctrls[],
    LDAPControl *cctrls[], int *msgidp);
```

I can provide the username by simply accessing `bv_val` and assigning value to it and I can provide the length of the username in `bv_len`. But  how do I provide password ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BerValue `bv_val` should be a pointer to the binary representation of the password string, you don't need to provide a username in this berval since the function `ldap_sasl_bind` uses the bind `dn` passed in as second parameter.

Something like the following should work (C++) :

```
berval cred;
cred.bv_val = (char*)password.c_str();
cred.bv_len = password.length();

res = ldap_sasl_bind(ld, dn, LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE, cred, sctrls, cctrls, msgidp);
```

Constant `LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE` is equivalent to `''` or `NULL`.